# Uniform convergence on the compact metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $f_n$ and $g_n$ be sequences of continuous functions from the metric space into the complex plane. If $\Sigma g_n$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $X$ and the absolute value of $f_n$ is equal or smaller than the absolute value of $g_n$ for each $n$, then, it is clear that $\Sigma f_n$ converges absolutely on $X$. However how can I show that $\Sigma f_n$ converges uniformly on $X$? I tried the Weierstrass M-test but failed... Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Use Cauchy convergence criterion.

Comment: What is Cauchy convergence criterion? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: If $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\forall m\geq n>N$,  $|\sum_{k=n}^m f_n |<\varepsilon,$ then $ f_n$ converges uniformly.  The google translation tells me that it is called *Cauchy convergence criterion*,  which I'm not sure about.

Comment: I tried that too but cannot apply it to $f_n$. I cannot bound the partial sum of $f_n$ by $g_n$. Could you show me your way?

Comment: It is sufficient and necessary to show that $\sum |g_n|$ conveges uniformly. And by Dini's theorem, it is equivalent to show $\sum|g_n|$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**This is wrong. It assumes that $\sum |g_n|$ converges uniformly, which does not follow from the assumptions.**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g_n|$ converges uniformly, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n \ge n_0 \implies \forall x\in X \text{ holds }\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |g_k(x)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty |g_k(x)|- \sum_{k=1}^n|g_k(x)|\right| < \varepsilon$$

Now for $M, N \ge n_0$ and $x \in X$ we have:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^M f_k(x)- \sum_{k=1}^N f_k(x)\right|= \left|\sum_{k=N+1}^M f_k(x)\right| \le \sum_{k=N+1}^M |f_k(x)| \le \sum_{k=N+1}^M |g_k(x)| \le \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |g_k(x)| < \varepsilon$$

Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ is uniformly Cauchy. This means that $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ is Cauchy in $C(X)$, the space of all continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the uniform metric: $$d_\infty(f_1, f_2) = \sup_{x \in X} |f_1(x) - f_2(x)|$$
Since $(C(X), d_\infty)$ is a complete metric space, the series $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ converges with respect to $d_\infty$, which in turn implies that $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Only the sum of $g_n$ converges uniformly. It is not that the sum of absolute value of $g_n$ converges uniformly. How can I prove that  the sum of absolute value of $g_n$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @Keith Ah, I see. It does not have to follow from uniform and absolute convergence of $\sum g_n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_absolute-convergence).

Comment: In the link there is the "distinction" between two concepts. What I intend is the uniform 'and' absolute convergence of $g_n$ not uniform absolute convergence.

Comment: @Keith I know, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: @Keith Wait, but your problem states that $|f_n(x)| \le g_n(x)$. This automatically implies $g(x) \ge 0$ so $|g(x)| = g(x)$.

Comment: Oh sorry I will correct that.

Comment: @Keith Then this statement is false. Let $g_n$ be the sequence from the link, with the property that $\sum g_n$ converges absolutely and uniformly, but $\sum |g_n|$ does not converge absolutely. Now take $f_n := |g_n|$. For this sequence we certainly have $|f_n| \le |g_n|$ but $\sum f_n = \sum |g_n|$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: I meant 'but $\sum |g_n|$ does not converge uniformly'. Ah, wait, the domain must be compact. I'm not sure then.